# Switching between multiple iframes

Tags: iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access few parameters which is inside of a iFrame and the iFrame is inside of another iFrame. I'm not able to access it. It simply throw an error as `no such frames` And I am not able to fine main from in the webpage. Need suggestions on this.
Find below the sample code:

```
<IFRAME id=ivuFrm_page0ivu1 style="HEIGHT: 504px; WIDTH: 100%" src="dummy" frameBorder=0 name="My Efforts " fullPage="true"></IFRAME>
```

The above iframe is under below iframe:

```
<IFRAME id=ivuFrm_page0ivu1 onload=setTitle(); style="HEIGHT: 508px; WIDTH: 100%" src="dummy" frameBorder=0 name="Desktop Innerpage " fullPage="true"></IFRAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to parent frame first ie `Desktop Innerpage` and then switch to `My Efforts`

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
// Switch to parent frames if any
driver.switchTo().frame("Desktop Innerpage ");
driver.switchTo().frame("My Efforts ");
// Now try to find element
```

Comment: all these frames are inside a td of a table..and those tables are inside another td of another main table. –

Comment: It doesn't matter if iframe is inside table or any other HTML element. Add complete HTML

Comment: complete html has some 4000 lines of code..i guess i cant put that here

Comment: @MuthuKumar You need to switch to every parent frame before switching to `My Efforts ` frame. Check if `Desktop Innerpage ` is within any other frames